# Print numbers in excel file when a string is found in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to print the numbers in excel file when a string is in the cell of the column and when there is nothing in the cell print the previous number.[image]

Now as the string is present in the 8th row of the column A the value 3 will be incremented and will be 4 and as the 9th row of the column A is empty so it will print 4 again and so on..
any ideas?Because it takes alot of time manually..

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question? How did you arrive at the numbers 1, 2 and 3 above your selected cell? Any text you enter in a cell will overwrite the formula there - can the numbers and text be in separate columns?

Comment: Is it an option to export as pipe delimited list and run the list through some processing or does if have to be done on an excel file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code already? I would think the easiest way to meet the requirements as you've described them would be to manipulate the workbook as an Excel.Workbook object in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx. Then you can traverse the cells in A and use a counter to do what you want.

Comment: Also, if it doesn't have to be C#, you could accomplish the same thing with a VBA macro in just a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here's a method that will do what you exactly asked for.. And it is important to save it with another name because the file is already open and cannot be saved, use xls format to save, if you try xlsx format to save with then your file will be corrupted, gotta sleep cause i have work in the morning.
Please do mark this as an answer if it helped to solve your problem.

```
public static void ReadExcel()
    {
        var excelObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        Workbook workbook;
        Worksheet worksheet;
        Range range;

        workbook = excelObject.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Book1.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        var sheet = workbook.Worksheets;

        worksheet = (Worksheet)sheet.get_Item(1);
        var last = worksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
        var usedRange = worksheet.get_Range("B1", last);
        var lastNumber = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= usedRange.Count; i++)
        {
            range = (Range)worksheet.Cells[i, 1];
            var strData = "";
            try
            {
                strData = range.Value2.ToString();
                if (Regex.IsMatch(strData, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
                {
                    lastNumber++;
                }
                else
                {
                    var temp = 0;
                    int.TryParse(range.Value2.ToString(), out temp);
                    if (temp > lastNumber)
                        lastNumber = temp;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                if (range.Value2 == null)
                {
                    if (lastNumber == 0)
                        lastNumber++;
                    range.Value2 = lastNumber;
                }
            }
        }

        workbook.SaveAs("C:\\tempBook.xls", true);
        workbook.Close();
    }
```